# Can't scrape nested tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying my hands on web scraping and I am currently stuck on how to get the href link from the 'a' tag which is nested in 2 divs which in turn is inside 'li' tag.

For instance for easy depiction of the problem, consider the following code:

```
<li class="top">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">
       <div class= "d">...</div>
       <div class= "e"> <a href="link.com" class= "f">..</a>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="top">Same kind of classes as before with different link </li>
<li class="top">Same kind of classes as before with different link</li>
```

And here I want to get the link.com. Also, the same class names are present for each list item. So how do I scrape this link.com
Please note that for the real code refer to the link below:
[Please  click here for the Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyS0A.jpg)

I had tried various things which I searched via other similar questions but none of them worked for me.

```py
jobs=soup.find_all('li', {"class": "top"})

for job in jobs:
  #  linkk=job.select("div.b > div.c > div.e > a[href]")
   # linkk
   # link1= job.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "b"})
   # link2= link1.findAll('div', attrs = {"class": "c"})
   # link3= link2.findAll('div', attrs={"class": "e"})
    link4= job.findAll('a', attrs={"class":"f"}).get('href')
    print(link4)
```

Please see that this code contains various techniques I had tried so this shouldn't be used as reference in whole. I just want to know how to get the href part of this 'a' tag.

Thanks in advance!
P.S. Hesitant because my first question on Stack Overflow

Comment: Can you share which web page you are trying to scrap?

Comment: Actually its LinkedIn. I am trying to find the links of all the content writers.
The url:
https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=freelance%20content%20writer&origin=RELATED_SEARCH_FROM_SRP&page=1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to get the best help consider reading  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MichaelD please review as I tried to simplify the problem for better readability.

Comment: Note, in this particular case you won't have anything in your `for` loop as the `li` element won't be found

Comment: @MichaelD right sorry for the discrepancy that was being carried forward from the real question which has various list items with same classes.

Comment: @VIPULVAIBHAV Can you check if `soup.body` is showing li tag just to check if beautifulsoup parsing full HTML?

Comment: links = [i[href'] for i in soup.select('.f')]  Use the _a_ tag class attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the element you want to access is created after js execution(Work only for logged user) so if your existing code if you check soup.body you won't be able to see that li tag.

So, If the page use JS to load the data dynamically in your case it is so you have to use selenium.

I have created a sample for you. Hope this will help!

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=freelance%20content%20writer&origin=RELATED_SEARCH_FROM_SRP&page=1"

driver = webdriver.Chrome('Path to ChromeDriver') 

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(150) #experiment with timer to fetch all the data
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
container = soup.find_all('li', attrs={
    'class':'search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view'})

for c in container:
    for link in c.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'search-result__result-link ember-view'}):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Download ChromDriver form here[https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads]
P.S. Check your chrome version to download driver.

Comment: True! Found out that the website loads dynamically which was creating the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @VIPULVAIBHAV Sure! I hope now you are able to get the expected result. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are getting multiple values in the second `find_all`. So you will need to loop these as well to do the `get("href")`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<li class="top"><div class="b"><div class="c"><div class= "d">...</div><div class= "e"> <a href="link.com" class= "f">..</a></div></div></div></li>')

job = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'top'})

for j in job:
    for i in j.find_all('a', {'class':'f'}):
        print(i.get('href'))
```

Output

```
link.com
```